# jsonschema 2.6.0 is installed but jsonschema>=3.0.1<4 is required by {'flask-appbuilder'}

Tags: apache-superset

I'm setting up Apache Superset 0.28.1. when I use command as follows `python setup.py install`, I get an error:

> error: jsonschema 2.6.0 is installed but jsonschema>=3.0.1<4 is required by {'flask-appbuilder'}

Answer (score 0):

Superset does not impose jsonschema dependency. Take a look at requirements.txt.
New FAB 1.13.0 includes jsonschema. You probably have jsonschema already installed. So you have several options:

- Upgrade or uninstall your current jsonschema.
- Force downgrade of FAB to 1.12.5

Answer (score 0):

you have to upgrade jsonschema it can be done by the following command it helps me
"conda install -c anaconda jsonschema"